# What are valid Perl module return values?

Tags: perl, module

The common practice in Perl is of course to end modules with `1;` so that a call to require can then be checked for success.  Is there any reason that the return value couldn't be another true value?  In my testing, it does not see to cause any problems, but I'd like to know if anyone has run across any issues (such as some other modules or pragmas or anything that expect the value actually to be `1` and not just true).

Edit: By popular opinion, and since it will only work once (good tip), the code example is gone.  Seems the consensus is that its safe to return any true value, but never to rely on  the that value in calling code since `require` will return `1` after the first loading

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: i hate typing the same thing twice. i agree, i have a refactoring problem, i've been attending meetings...

Comment: Refactoring is one thing, golfing is another. ;)

Comment: If you don't like typing, why are you returning a package name instead of an object? :)

Comment: @Eric: One day in future we'll find the question on SO: "What does the code `(require My::Module)->new` doing?" :)

Comment: I'm so tempted to post that question, but can't quite muster the gumption.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've been putting silly things at the end of my modules for a while.  There's no harm and its a little Easter egg.  [uny2k](http://search.cpan.org/dist/uny2k) helpfully ends with `"Yes, this code is a joke."`  [Class::Fields](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-Fields) is chock full of them.

Taking it one step further, sometimes when a function is documented to return `true` and `false` I will return something other than 1 for `true`.  This is to punish people who write `if foo() == 1` when they mean `if foo()`.  This was around the same period I was writing `use constant TRUE => 1==1;  use constant FALSE => !TRUE;`

I have seen the return value of a module used in production code.  I don't recall exactly why.  The developer's logic was... tortured.  I believe it was something along the lines of not wanting to have to write just one line instead of two.  I don't remember why he didn't just export it.

This was the same developer who used `%_` to pass arguments around (the `*_` symbol is global *across packages*) and wrote 150 line map statements inside map statements.

The danger of using the return value, aside from obfuscation, is that it only works once.

```
$ cat Foo.pm
package Foo;

return "Basset hounds got long ears";

$ cat test.plx
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

print require Foo, "\n";
print require Foo, "\n";

$ perl -I. test.plx
Basset hounds got long ears
1
```

The first call to `require` evaluates Foo.pm and returns the return value.  The second call sees its already in `%INC` and just returns true.  And you can't even be sure that you're the first thing to require the code.  You can get around this with `do "Foo.pm"` but now you're reloading the module each time with warnings about redefined routines, problems for performance and possibly reinitializing globals.  Its not worth it.

Answer (score 8):

I think (1) there's no problem with returning any arbitrary true value from your module but (2) there's a *big* problem with the obscure, overly-clever code you suggest to exploit the module implementation details. Don't do that.

Answer (score 7):

Anything is a valid return value. If you want the `require` to succeed, it needs to be a true value. If you don't want the `require` to succeed (e.g. unsupported platform, missing library), use a false value.

To see what other people have used as return values, check out [Acme::ReturnValue](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Acme-ReturnValue).

People don't expect to use the return value for anything, so I wouldn't confuse people by trying to do that, no matter how clever it seems at the time. :)

Answer (score 6):

[Mark Dominus](http://perl.plover.com/), author of [*Higher-Order Perl*](http://hop.perl.plover.com/), explains my favorite:

> I have very rarely used `$flag = 'Cogito ergo sum';` which as everyone
>   knows is self-evidently true in all possible universes.  This ensures
>   maximum portability.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose is that if your module returns false, the require can fail at that point.  Nobody cares about or relies on the value beyond it being true or false.

You should follow suit.  You are making it so that *your* modules depend on the actual value beyond whether it is true or false.  In the example you gave, for instance, if your require happens to return `1`, the require will succeed, but your clever constructor will fail.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you'll run into with `require` is that it only returns the module's return value the first time that the module is loaded. If the module was already loaded, require returns 1 without loading the module again.

The `do file` statement will reload the file each time, and returns the file's return value each time. I've used it to store configuration data in a file in the form of an anonymous hash.

Comment: `do file` "works", but it's really hard to perform error checking. You'd be much better off storing config data in a defined parsable format like YAML, rather than directly populating data structures in a separate library.

Comment: @Ether I can think of reasons not to stick config info into a Perl data structure (its insecure and unportable) but error checking isn't one of them.  Perl does the checking for you.  `do $file || die` is sufficient.