# Why the 1 at the end of each perl package?

Tags: perl, return-value, perl-module

If you forget the 1 at the end of a package, Perl tells you "The package didn't return a true value". Well, if it knows you forgot it, why not just put it there for you?

Comment: You want [true](http://p3rl.org/true).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Because Perl modules are required to return a value to signal if the `require` directive must succeed (true value returned) or fail (false value returned; this can make sense if the module failed to initialize for some reason).

If you don't return anything, the interpreter cannot know if the `require` must succeed or fail; at the same time, since it's easy to forget to put the true value at the end of the package, it suggests the "common fix" for this error: add a true value as a return.

For some other info/folklore about the modules return value have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860869/what-are-valid-perl-module-return-values).

Comment: If you forgot to put it there, wouldn't that mean you probably didn't need to signal any kind failed initialization? Since it seems like it would be a very specialized case, can't we safely assume that it'll succeed unless we're telling it that there's a chance it won't succeed?

Comment: @Chris: we can argue about what would be better or more logical, but the language has been designed in this way, talking about it won't change this behavior. `:)` (personally, I think that it's better like it is now: if a return value is requested, then you *have* to specify it)

Comment: @Matteo - Since Perl 6 still very much in the "indefinite future" stage of development, I think talking about the language _can_ (and almost certainly will) change it's behavior.

Comment: @Chris: sure, I'm talking about the current Perl; still, I don't think they will change it, first of all for the "if a return value is requested, then you have to specify it" thing, and then because the whole "return strange true values" has become part of the Perl folklore. `:)`

Comment: The module fails to initialize if you forget to return a true value anyway. Also, when was the last time you returned a false value from your production module and allowed it to generate a run time error?

Comment: @Minimalist: see my first comment directed @Chris: the fact that you don't like it won't change the way the (current) language works. I can rant for a day about how I think PHP is awful, yet this won't change it of a iota.

Comment: I actually find this kind of pointless. If you want the load to fail, just call `die`. Seriously, the only time I have had a module end with a false value, it was because I forgot to put a `1;` at the end.

Comment: It doesn't have a practical use any more, not compared to the continuous annoyance it provides.  And removing the requirement doesn't stop `$ret = require Foo` from continuing to work.  As for there being no point about ranting and complaining and wanting the language to be different... this is Perl.  We bring our own change.  Have a look at `true.pm` and `perl5i` both eliminate this misfeature.  It's also possible this could come in as a `use 5.16` feature.

Answer (score 5):

A package can return a false value if it fails to initialize, for example if it couldn't find a required data file or external library. This way it fails cleanly at load time (and this failure can even be tested for) rather than unpredictably later.

Comment: A package *can* return a false value if it fails to initialize, but it shouldn't. It would be better off dieing with a useful message.

Answer (score 4):

> 1;
>
> When a module is loaded (via use)
> the compiler will complain unless the
> last statement executed when it is
> loaded is true. This line ensures that
> this is the case (as long as you don't
> place any code after this line). It's
> Perl's way of making sure that it
> successfully parsed all the way to the
> end of the file.

See [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219235647/http://mathforum.org/ken/perl_modules.html)

You can use any statement that evaluates as true. 1 just happened to a become a perl idiom.

Answer (score 4):

From [wikipedia Perl module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_module):

```
   A Perl module must end with a true value or else it is considered not to
   have loaded.  By convention this value is usually 1 though it can be
   any true value.  A module can end with false to indicate failure but
   this is rarely used and it would instead die() (exit with an error).
```