# returning -1 from perl module

Tags: perl, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are valid Perl module return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860869/what-are-valid-perl-module-return-values)

Generally we use `1;` at the end of the module. This is to indicate that module returns `true` and can be imported properly. Now if we return `0` means `false`, that means module fails in import.

My question is, What if I use (or return) below statements at the end of module

- `-1;`
- `some text;`
- or `abc;`

Does `-1` means error, and `some text`,`abc` means `true`

Also  what if I don't use `1;` or any statement (as above) at all, what does module return in that case?

Does it return `undef`?

Comment: Shouldn't return zero even for failure. Should always return true or die.

Comment: You could return `0E0`; that means zero, but it isn't false...On second thoughts, you shouldn't return `0E0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any true value indicates success.  -1 is a true value.

The return doesn't have to be at the end of the file; it is the return value of the last executable statement (that is, the last statement that isn't just a compile-time thing like package, use, no, sub, format).

For example, the requiring a file containing the following:

```
package foo;
our @x;
sub bar { }
```

will fail if @foo::x is empty and otherwise succeed.

If there indeed are no executable statements, the return value is taken to be undef (false).

Answer (score 2):

Just like for a sub, the value returned by a module is the value returned by the last statement evaluated. I imagine it's undef if the file is empty. (It's definitely not a true value.)

A module should always return a true value (anything other than zero, the empty string or undef).

- `-1` is true, so that's acceptable.
- `some text` is an indirect method call equivalent for `text->some()`.

  - `text->some()` (and equivalent) is acceptable if and only if the method returns a true value. I would follow up with a true constants to be safe.
- `abc` is either a subroutine call equivalent to `abc()`, or a string literal equivalent to `'abc'`.

  - `abc()` (and equivalent) is acceptable if and only if the subroutine returns a true value. I would follow up with a true constants to be safe.
  - `'abc'` (and equivalent) is true, so that's acceptable.

If there's an error, `die` instead. But even that should be avoided if reasonable as it leaves the module half-loaded (half-executed) if someone catches the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Those are true and the module will compile. However, under more aggressive diagnostics I've seen compilers emit a warning about values other than 1. Actually this "1;" can be placed on any line. I sometimes put such in the middle of code I'm debugging just to have nice debugging break point lines.

A lot of programs out there run without trouble at lower diagnostic levels by accidentally having various true values in the last expression, which need not be the last line.

```
$a = "True value to accidentally keep -c happy.";

sub hello { return; }
```